# How can I do to make Ubuntu 14.04 to startup where I left in last session?

Tags: 14.04, startup, session

I just haven't been able to configurate Ubuntu 14.04 so that it starts up in the last session, just like before I shut it down

Comment: Use hibernate / suspend instead of shutdown?

Answer (score 0):

You can hibernate instead of shutting down.

Run these commands to enable it :

```
sudo -i

touch /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla

echo "[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
ResultActive=yes" >> /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
```

Then reboot.

You should now have a `Hibernate` option in your power menu.

Source : http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-14-04/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, hibernate [doesn't work](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/power-suspendfail.html) in many cases, which can cause you to lose data if you expect your documents and applications to re-open when you switch your computer back on. Therefore, hibernate is disabled by default.

### Test if hibernate works

*Note* : **Always save your work before hibernating**
You should save all of your work before hibernating the computer, just in case something goes wrong and your open applications and documents cannot be recovered when you switch on the computer again.

You can use the command line to test if hibernate works on your computer.

1. Open the Terminal by pressing
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or by searching for
   terminal in the Dash.
2. Type `sudo pm-hibernate` into the terminal and press
   <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
   Enter your password when prompted.
3. After you computer turns off, switch it back on. Did your open applications re-open?

**If hibernate doesn't work, check if your swap partition is at least as large as your available RAM.**

### Enable hibernate

If the hibernate test works, you can continue to use the `sudo pm-hibernate` command when you want to hibernate.

You can also enable the hibernate option in the menus. To do that, use your favorite text editor to create `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla`. Add the following to the file and save:

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate; org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions
ResultActive=yes
```

*Source* : [Official Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html)